# last_insert_id oracle

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, crud

Tenho uma dúvida sobre banco oracle.

Criei duas tabelas e setei uma delas com um campo com foreing key (ver abaixo o FK)

**tbl_cidade**
*id_city* (PK e auto incremento) - gerado com sequence, visto que não temos auto_increment no oracle

*municipio*

**tbl_escolas**
*cod (PK)*

*escola*

*id_city (FK)*

Como diabos monto um INSERT para popular as duas tabelas? Até hj só montei insert’s pra UMA tabelas no oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cláusula RETURNING em seu comando INSERT:

INSERT INTO tbl_cidade (...) VALUES (...)
RETURNING id_city INTO var_id;

e depois utilize var_id no INSERT da tabela tbl_escolas.

Comment: Tipo isso?


http://pastebin.com/ZKU9cbut#

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!